# Get start and end date of current week which starts in one month and ends in another month

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I have to get start date and and end date of current week. I used this code but end date is getting previous month name if week start in one month and ends in another month.

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function (start) {

   start = start || 0;

   var today = new Date(this.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));

   var day = today.getDay() - start;

   var date = today.getDate() - day;

   var StartDate = new Date(today.setDate(date));

   var EndDate = new Date(today.setDate(date + 6));

    return [StartDate, EndDate];
}

var Dates = new Date().getWeek();

  alert(Dates[0].toLocaleDateString() + ' to ' + Dates[1].toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: can you use the excellent datetime javascript library momentjs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below simple javascript code:

```
var mondate = new Date();
var sundate = new Date();
var monday = 0;
var sunday = 6;

var mondayDate = mondate.setDate(monday);
var sundayDate = sundate.setDate(sunday);

alert("Monday date is "+new Date(mondayDate)+" and Sunday date is "+new Date(sundayDate));
```

Comment: Thank You Ankur... can you pls make it startdate as sunday and endate as saturday in a week

Comment: set  variable monday = -1 (for the previous sunday) and set sunday = 5(for coming saturday), rename variable monday and sunday as Sunday and saturday respectively for better understanding.

Hope this work for you :)

Comment: Lavanya, Is your problem solved ??

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Comment: Hi Ankur, this is not working for normal weeks.. That means week starts and ends in same month